# Unable to generate regex for username

Tags: regex

Expectation: Min 6 and Max 30 characters. It can contain letters, numbers, and period( .), cannot begin and end with a period, consecutive period( . ) not allowed.

I'm trying to generate regex which  is `^(?!\.)(?!.*\.$)(?!.*?\.\.)[a-zA-Z0-9_.]+$`, but this is not working as expected

Comment: Replace `+` with `{6,30}`

Comment: When posting questions, please provide actual descriptions of the problem; "not working as expected" is not one; you should instead explain what it does and why that is wrong.

Comment: You could also use a single lookahead for the number of characters `^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_.]{6,30}$)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$` or shorter `^(?=[\w.]{6,30}$)\w+(?:\.\w+)*$`

Comment: ^(?=[\w.]{6,30}$)\w+(?:\.\w+)*$  wil this regex satisfy this condition :-cannot begin and end with a period, consecutive period( . ) not allowed. @Thefourthbird 

I

Comment: The pattern starts and ends with a word char, and optionally contains a single period followed by 1 or more word chars.

Comment: [https://regex101.com/ ] I'm unable to test this here. can you provide some test data @Thefourthbird

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/CSrgYY/1

Comment: this only needs to contain letters, numbers and period. which means no special character @Thefourthbird